# StorageReference to URL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimageview, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to follow Firebase's documentation on how to display a image from firebase Storage to the user in app. This is that documentation below:

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

I try to do this myself:

```
//get image url from deal
self.ref.child("deals").child("log").child(currentDealView).child("pictures").child(currentImageView).child("imageSelected").child("imageSelected").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let imageUrlString = snapshot.value as! String
    let imageUrlUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString)

    print(imageUrlString)
    //prints "deals/log/dealNumber83/pictures/googleScreenshot/imageSelected"

    // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
    let reference = self.storageRef.child(imageUrlString)

    // UIImageView in your ViewController
    let viewPicImageView: UIImageView = self.viewPicImageView

    // Placeholder image
    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

    // Load the image using SDWebImage

    viewPicImageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

but on the very last line I have a error at "with: reference," saying: "Cannot convert value of type 'StorageReference' to expected argument type 'URL?'" I can't find any info online on how to convert a `StorageReference` to a `URL`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
let Ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imageUrlUrl)
Ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: Image could not download!")
    } else {
        yourImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: If I use `{forURL: imageUrlUrl}` I get a error "Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'String'". If I change that to `{forURL: imageUrlString}` then the app crashes and I get the error "Thread 1: Exception: "URL scheme must be one of gs://, http://, or https:// ""

Comment: When you tap download image at storage it gives you a url. Write this to your code.

Comment: I got it to work using your code (thanks) and I realized my problem was that imageURLString was "deals/x/x/pic", I changed that string to "gs://myap-gd36f.appspot.com/deals/x/x/pic" instead and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with the FirebaseStorageSwift beta taking advantage of the Swift Result type. (Add `pod 'FirebaseStorageSwift'` to the Podfile.)

```
let Ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imageUrlUrl)
Ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { result in
  switch result {
  case let .success(data):
    yourImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
  case let .failure(error):
    print("Error: Image could not download! \(error)")
  }
}
```